# Why when OntClass create an individual behave not properly?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

The problem is:
I expect this code to have rdf:type property of that special Individual, but the model.write method gives me such output:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://microhard.com/graph/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:j.1="http://microhard.com/property/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://microhard.com/graph/POI"/>
  <j.0:POI>
    <j.1:p1>111</j.1:p1>
  </j.0:POI>
</rdf:RDF>
```

this is the code:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String NS = "http://microhard.com/graph/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
        OntClass klass = m.createClass(NS + "POI");
        Individual in = klass.createIndividual();
        in.addProperty(m.createProperty("http://microhard.com/property/p1"), "111");
        m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML");

    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the type is set. If you want a named individual, createIndividual() needs an argument.

Answer (score 3):

it is a typed blank node:

[RDF/XML 2.13 Typed Node Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-typed-nodes)